# How to create different bar charts using same data based on certain criteria using formulas

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am creating a chart in Excel form:

[image: Sample data which I am working on]

As I am denied VBA for security reasons, I want to create a dynamic chart where I should get three separate charts of `Bears`, `Dolphins` and `Whales` with the help of formulas. To sum up, when I provide following data then in other sheet I require to build bears chart different for Month Jan - Jun and vice versa.

Comment: If you are looking for dynamic data series ranges, try [Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4D0F13AC-53B7-422E-AFD2-ABD7FF379C64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with the comment that user "Jeeped" left.

Although not scalable, have you considered a different structure with a pivot table and slicer?

i.e. have your data as {Month, Animal, Value} and run a pivot from there?
You can have a separate pivot linked for each chart and then apply the slicer to multiple graphs.
[image]

e.g. you can have a graph for each animal, and then connect a slicer for the month to all three.
[image]